# Cloud Dataflow: Error syncing pod, ... ErrImage Pull: code = Unknown desc,.., failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with ImagePullBackOff

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I tried to run a simple apache beam java pipeline on Cloud Dataflow but kept running into the following error message. The job graph is displayed on the cloud console, but its not progressing and the error show up in the diagnostics tab

```
Error syncing pod ccd0b94434fa6d8bd27fa1a35c7bbaa1 ("df-logger-pipeline-v1-12271813-9q0o-harness-th9v_default(ccd0b94434fa6d8bd27fa1a35c7bbaa1)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "java-streaming" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/beam-java17-streaming:2.32.0 not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch \"2.32.0\" from request \"/v2/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/beam-java17-streaming/manifests/2.32.0\".""
```

Seeing that the error had something to do with the docker registry, I also went to enable APIs for artifact registry, tried using a couple of different beam versions - 2.34.0, 2.32.0, used a service account key with owner permissions, but nothing worked.

Then I went back to the word count walkthrough [tutorial](https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started?walkthrough_tutorial_id=java_dataflow_quickstart&_ga=2.188814059.155918902.1640569605-863678478.1640231631) and tried it out, and ran into the same error messages even though I went though all the steps according to the tutorial (enable APIs, creating bucket, using a service account key with basic:owner permissions, etc.). Not sure what else I can try, since I'm already using provided tutorial code and am following all the steps.

[image]

Would be great if I could get some help, thanks!

job_id: "2021-12-27_18_13_05-12225486947056516903"

Previous job_ids for running wordcount tutorial: "2021-12-26_20_27_47-2726658310426059434", "2021-12-26_20_44_57-11186493226221699", "2021-12-26_21_03_11-13957180745820764137"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're pulling a non existing image"beam-java17-streaming/manifests/2.32.0"

Beam Java currently supports Java 8, Java 11, and will add support for Java 17 by end of the year
Beam Python currently supports Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and will add support for Python 3.9 by end of the year.

Older SDK versions support different python and java versions.

Try with one of the supported JDK versions (8 or 11) and let me know how it goes?

Potential pages to publish this information:

1. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status#java
2. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#sdk-for-java
3. https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/#releases

Comment: Thanks! That was spot on!